# Strange white pixel border - IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I´m having this problem with border radius on IE-9

[image]

As you can see it creates some white pixel on the left border. any ideas why is that?

**This only happens on IE 9,** all other browsers are ok

This is the markup:

```
                    <ul class="tags clearfix">
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Etiqueta Uno</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Otra etiqueta</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul><!-- tags -->
```

This is the CSS:

```
#article_sidebar ul.tags li {
    background: #000000;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    padding: 0px 18px 0px 19px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: did you zoom in on the page in IE9?

Comment: no, it´s on 100% zoom

Comment: I don't get this issue. Here's my demo tested in IE9

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle that we can compare it to?

Answer (score 1):

@fxg Why don't you also try making an **IE-Only Stylesheet**. You can refer [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) for making a stylesheet, that will target only IE and in that stylesheet you can give

```
li{
    border: 0 none;
}
```

Hope, that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's a rounding error. This can happen under certain conditions, such as when the calculated value is a non-terminated floating point value (ie - 3.3333333...). Depending on how the browser does its rounding, this can create a visual error, such as what you're seeing.

Take a look at your padding value. Notice how your padding-right is 18px, and the right side doesn't have this issue, but your padding-left is 19px? Try changing your padding-left to 18px and see if that fixes the issue.

Also, try changing your border-radius value to something a little larger, such as 3px or 4px and see if it changes anything.

Also, make sure that you haven't accidentally zoomed in slightly. You can ensure your browser's zoom is reset by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `overflow: hidden;` for `li`s, and/or `outline: none;` for `a`s.